# Linked List: Dequeue correctly returns popped data, but segmentation fault occurs when attempting to use print

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am attempting to implement a Linked List in C, and for the most part it seems to work. But when I attempt to use the queue/dequeue functionality things fall apart.

In the debugging printf statement below, the output which is to be returned is able to print out fine when I've queued up a string. But when I attempt to use it outside of the function when it's returned I ended up with a segmentation fault.

Functions like _next() work perfectly fine.

```
void* LinkedList_dequeue(LinkedList* list)
{
    Node* beforeNext = NULL;                            //Keep track of node before cursor
    Node* toDelete;                                     //Remember to free memory!
    void* output;

    if(LinkedList_isEmpty(list)){                       //Check if list is empty
        return NULL;                                    //Empty; return NULL
    }else{                                              //List is not empty; continue
        while(LinkedList_isNext(list)){                 //Iterate to end.
            beforeNext = list->cursor;
            LinkedList_next(list);
        }
        output = list->cursor->data;
        toDelete = list->cursor;
        if(beforeNext){                                 //beforeNext is not NULL
            beforeNext->next = NULL;                    //Sever connection
        }else{
            list->cursor = NULL;                        //Else, set cursor to NULL
            list->head   = NULL;
        }

        LinkedList_resetCursor(list);                   //Reset cursor.

        Node_free(toDelete);                            //Clean up
        printf("Output: %s\n", output);                 //TODO DEBUG
        return output;  
    }
}
```

Structs:

```
/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
/*STRUCT:                                                                   */
/*      LinkedList                                                          */
/*Linked List data structure                                                */
/*                                                                          */
/*Members:                                                                  */
/*      Node* head:                                                         */
/*          The head node of the list                                       */
/*      Node* cursor:                                                       */
/*          Internal pointer                                                */
/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
typedef struct LinkedList{
    Node* head;
    Node* cursor;
} LinkedList;
#endif


/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
/*STRUCT:                                                                   */
/*      Node                                                                */
/*Nodes for LinkedList struct                                               */
/*                                                                          */
/*Members:                                                                  */
/*      Node* next:                                                         */
/*          Appended child node                                             */
/*      void* data:                                                         */
/*          Data held in the node                                           */
/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
typedef struct Node{
    struct Node* next;
    void* data;
} Node;
```

If the rest of my code is needed I can also post that as well.

Comment: Run in a debugger to learn exactly where and when the crash happens.

Comment: Let's see... Looks like str_len() is setting off the segfault according to gdb. Looking into it further it appears that the memory is not accessible anyways: `$1 = 0x1e98 <Address 0x1e98 out of bounds>`
Hmm. Maybe it somehow ended up on the stack of the function somehow, and that's why it's only printable inside of the function? Since it would have been popped.

Answer (score 1):

My guess it's these lines that are the culprit:

```
output = list->cursor->data;
toDelete = list->cursor;

...

Node_free(toDelete);                            //Clean up
printf("Output: %s\n", output);
```

First you make `output` point to `cursor->data` then you free `cursor`, maybe freeing the `data` as well? In that case when you next dereference `output` you dereference a pointer to unallocated memory, leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The simple solution? Print *before* you free the node.

Comment: Oh, that `printf()` statement actually works completely fine. There's one that's being used in the caller (main) that's attempting to print the returned value, but fails despite it having printed successfully the line right before it was returned.

Comment: @Saxophlutist Be happy that it works on your system. It may cease working the instant `malloc(3)` decides to change the way it works, like on OpenBSD where `free(3)` overwrites all memory that has been free'd or returns it to the operating system *instantly*.